# How to preserve file mode with rsync, except for setuid bits?

Tags: files, permissions, rsync

I run into a "Disk quota exceeded (122)" error if I use `rsync -p <args>` to copy files around.

```
rsync -rlptD --chown username:org1 -- local/ /project/org1/
```

I would like to preserve source read and execute bits on files and directories, but force the destination to have group setuid `g+s` on directories.

The reason for wanting `g+s` on directories is so that new files inherit the project's group ownership. In my environment, if files within project folders (e.g. `/project/foo/`) are owned by my personal group (groupname == username), I run into the quota error.

I've given the `--chown username:org1` argument to rsync as an attempt to force usage of group `org1` throughout, but it's insufficient. I think there's a race condition where rsync applies the desired `user:group` ownership *after* the temporarily files are renamed to their final location.

If I remove the `-p` from the rsync flags, then I can transfer without errors, but I lose the permission bits from the source. Without `-p`, any temporary file created by rsync in the destination folder correctly inherits the project group from the root folder, and subfolders inherit the group setuid.

Is there a way to give rsync a mask of permissions to keep? I need bitmask 777 from the source, but `g+s` set (unconditionally) for remote directories.

Comment: 1. What file systems are you using (where you have the source and the target for the `rsync` copying process? 2. What operating system and 3. version of `rsync` are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `--chmod RULE[,RULE]*` option may help.

From [man rsync(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync):

> --chmod
>
> This  option tells rsync to apply one or more comma-separated "chmod" modes to the permission of the files in the transfer.  The resulting value is treated as though it were the permissions that
>   the sending side supplied for the file, which means that this option can seem to have no effect on existing files if --perms is not enabled.

Try `--chmod Dg+s` to force directories on the remote to have setuid on the directories.